# How set background color of each level in hierarchical jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I use free jqgrid(v5.1.1) in my asp.net mvc project.
In my view,I have 5 level hierarchical jqgrid. how can I set background color of header of each level? for example header of first level has "blue" color,second level has "green" color,third level has "light blue" color and....

here is my code:

```
 //************************************fill grid level 1 **********************************
function FillJQueryGrid(ProjectIdVal) {

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCodingCodeSumLists", "Report")' + '?ProjectId=' + ProjectIdVal,// jqgrid_data,

        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: function (obj) {
                return obj.records;
            }
        },
        datatype: "json",
        height: 'auto',
        page: 1,
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Fieco Doc No.', name: 'comp_code', key: true},
            { label: 'Subject', name: 'Comp_Subject' },
            { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count' },

        ],
        width:"100%",
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridrevision,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
        };

//***********************************fill grid level 2 *******************************************
    function showChildGridrevision(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
        var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
        var childGridPagerID = parentRowID + "_pager";

        var childGridURL = '@Url.Action("GetRevisionSumLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode=' + parentRowKey;

        $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

        $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
            url: childGridURL,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) {
                    return obj.records;
                }
            },
            datatype: "json",
            height: 'auto',
            width: "100%",

            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                {label:'CompCode_Revision',name:'CompCode_Revision',key:true,hidden:true},
                { label: 'comp_code', name: 'comp_code', hidden: true },
                { label: 'revision', name: 'revision',width:500 },
                { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count',width:500 }
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridTransmital,
            pager: "#" + childGridPagerID
        });

    }

    //***********************************fill grid level 3 *******************************************
    function showChildGridTransmital(parentRowID2, parentRowKey2) {
        debugger;
        var childGridID2 = parentRowID2 + "_table";
        var childGridPagerID2 = parentRowID2 + "_pager";

        var childGridURL2 = '@Url.Action("GetTransmitalSumLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode_Revision=' + parentRowKey2;

        $('#' + parentRowID2).append('<table id=' + childGridID2 + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID2 + ' class=scroll></div>');

        $("#" + childGridID2).jqGrid({
            url: childGridURL2,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) {
                    return obj.records;
                }
            },
            datatype: "json",
            height:'auto',
            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                { label: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital', name: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital', key: true,hidden:true},
                { label: 'CompCode_Revision', name: 'CompCode_Revision', hidden: true },
                { label: 'transmital no', name: 'trans_ref_no' ,width:200},
                { label: 'transmital subject', name: 'ChkMain_Subject' ,width:400},
                { label: 'transmital date', name: 'trans_date',width:200 },
                { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count',width:200 }
            ],

            width:'100%',
            loadonce: true,
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridReceiver,
            pager: "#" + childGridPagerID2
        });

    }

    //***********************************fill grid level 4 *******************************************
    function showChildGridReceiver(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
        debugger;
        var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
        var childGridPagerID = parentRowID + "_pager";

        var childGridURL = '@Url.Action("GetReceiverSumLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode_Revision_Transmital=' + parentRowKey;

        $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

        $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
            url: childGridURL,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) {

                    return obj.records;
                }
            },
            datatype: "json",
            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                { label: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital_receiver', name: 'CompCode_Revision_Transmital_receiver', key: true, hidden: true },
                { label: 'receiver_id', name: 'receiver_id',hidden:true },
                { label: 'Receiver Name', name: 'receiver_name',width:500 },
                { label: 'Delay', name: 'sum_delay_count', width: 500 }
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            height: '100%',
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: showChildGridLetter,
            pager: "#" + childGridPagerID
        });

    }
    //***********************************fill grid level 5 *******************************************
    function showChildGridLetter(parentRowID, parentRowKey) {
        debugger;
        var childGridID = parentRowID + "_table";
        var childGridPagerID = parentRowID + "_pager";

        var childGridURL = '@Url.Action("GetLettersOfCodingWithDelayLists", "Report")' + '?CompCode_Revision_Transmital_Receiver=' + parentRowKey;

        $('#' + parentRowID).append('<table id=' + childGridID + '></table><div id=' + childGridPagerID + ' class=scroll></div>');

        $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid({
            url: childGridURL,
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) {

                    return obj.records;
                }
            },
            datatype: "json",
            page: 1,

            colModel: [
                { label: 'DCC_letter_id', name: 'DCC_letter_id', key: true, hidden: true },
                { label: 'CommentLetter No', name: 'Let_no'},
                { label: 'Subject', name: 'Let_subject' ,width:300},
                { label: 'Estimate Date', name: 'estimate_date_of_letter' },
                { label: 'Send Date', name: 'Let_date' },
                { label: 'Delay', name: 'delay_count_of_letter'}
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            height: '100%',
            subGrid: false,
            pager: "#" + childGridPagerID
        });

    }
```

Comment: First of all, you use commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS instead of free jqGrid. You can open [jquery.jqGrid.min.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.1.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js#L6), which you use, and see "License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334", where the **prices** of the product under the [url](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the current version is 4.14.0) is another fork of jqGrid, which I develop, and which you can use really for free. About your question: you should post *more details* inclusive JavaScript code.

Comment: thanks Oleg,I use Guriddo jqGrid but all levels are the same

Comment: **You should post more details about what you do exactly inclusive JavaScript code.** One can not clear understand from your question even what you mean under "hierarchical jqgrid". Do yo use Grid with Subgrids, TreeGrid, data grouping and so on? It's unclear, whether you use jQuery UI CSS or Bootstrap. It would be good to post the demo, which would clear everything.

Comment: Thank you, I'll analyse your code and I'll post my answer later. One important thing (not directly related to your question) I would strictly recommend you: you should add `idPrefix` to all subgrids (different on every level and which depends on the parent `id`). For example `idPrefix: rowid + "_"` or `idPrefix: "g1" + rowid + "_"`, `idPrefix: "g2" + rowid + "_"`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to mention, that there are no **free jqGrid** v5.1.1. It's commercial version, which price you can see under under link, which you see in the comment at the beginning of [jquery.jqGrid.min.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.1.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js#L6): `"License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334%22"`. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is **alternative fork** of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end of 2014, after the end of "jqGrid" and renaming the fork to "Guriddo jqGrid JS".

The second important common remark: it's important, that one has no **id duplicates** on HTML page. Thus one should choose unique `id` values. In case of usage subgrids one can easy get id duplicates if multiple subgrids are opened. One can solve the problem in very easy way, by usage `idPrefix` in all subgrids. For example you can use

```js
idPrefix: parentRowKey + "_" // or parentRowKey2 + "_"
```

Now about your main problem. There are many ways to use `background-color` to allow the user to see the level of the grid. For example, every subgrid consist of two parts: `td.subgrid-cell` and `td.subgrid-data`. One can set background color on `td.subgrid-cell`. You will have the results like on the picture below

[image]

One more option will be setting background color on the column headers of every subgrid. The results will be like

[image]

If you would use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), then you can use `labelClasses` property of `colModel`. You need just add the property `labelClasses: "blue"` to `colModel` and to define the following CSS rule:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-labels .blue {
    background-color: #b3d9ff;
    background-image: none;
}
```

To add `labelClasses: "blue"` option to all columns of subgrid you can use `cmTemplate``option of the subgrid:

```js
cmTemplate: { labelClasses: "blue" }
```

The code of `subGridRowExpanded` could be the following:

```js
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowid) {
    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
        subgridData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).details,
        $subgridDataDiv = $("#" + subgridDivId),
        $subgridCell = $subgridDataDiv.closest(".subgrid-data").prev(".subgrid-cell");

    $subgridCell.addClass("blue"); // set background color on td.subgrid-cell
    $subgridDataDiv.append($subgrid);
    $subgrid.jqGrid({
        idPrefix: rowid + "_",
        data: subgridData,
        colModel: [
            { name: "c1", label: "Col 1" },
            { name: "c2", label: "Col 2" },
            { name: "c3", label: "Col 3" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { labelClasses: "blue" }, // set background color on column headers
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        autowidth: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortname: "c1"
    });
}
```

One will be need to add CSS rule like the following

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid .subgrid-cell.blue {
    background-color: #b3d9ff;
    background-image: none;
}
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/q5j6vnLa/.

If you have to use old jqGrid of Guriddo, then you can't use `labelClasses`, but you can use `setLabel` method, for example, to assign class on the column header.